# angr | populate int array with constraints

Tags: angr

How do I populate memory address using `angr` with array of integers (?) and add a constraint so each int will be positive & less than 17 ?

I hope it's clear I need to find out the `in_array` combination

chall.c

```
// gcc -m32 chall.c -o chall 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int p = 0;
int c = 1;
char d[45] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0};
char in_array[16] = {0};

int M(char *a1, int a2);
void BAD();
void GOOD();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (M(in_array, 16))
    GOOD();
}


int M(char *a1, int a2)
{
  char *v2; // r11
  unsigned int v3; // r10
  signed int v4; // r9
  int v5; // r6
  int v6; // r3
  int v7; // r4
  int v8; // r5
  signed int v9; // r8
  unsigned int v10; // r2
  unsigned int v11; // r1
  char v12; // r1
  int v14; // [sp+14h] [bp-34h]
  char v15[16]; // [sp+18h] [bp-30h]
  int v16; // [sp+28h] [bp-20h]

  v2 = a1;
  v3 = a2;
  if ( a2 >= 2 )
  {
    v4 = (unsigned int)a2 >> 1;
    M(a1, (unsigned int)a2 >> 1);
    if ( c )
    {
      v5 = (int) &v2[v3 >> 1];
      M(&v2[v3 >> 1], v3 - (v3 >> 1));
      if ( c )
      {
        v6 = v3 - (v3 >> 1);
        v14 = v3 - (v3 >> 1);
        if ( (signed int)(v3 - (v3 >> 1)) >= 1 )
        {
          v7 = 0;
          v8 = 0;
          v9 = 0;
          while ( 1 )
          {
            v10 = *(char *)(v5 + v8);
            v11 = v2[v9];
            if ( v11 >= v10 )
            {
              if ( v11 <= v10 || d[p] )
              {
LABEL_21:
                c = 0;
                BAD();
                // return 0;
              }
              ++p;
              v12 = *(char *)(v5 + v8++);
            }
            else
            {
              if ( d[p] != 1 )
                goto LABEL_21;
              v6 = v14;
              ++p;
              v12 = v2[v9++];
            }
            v15[v7++] = v12;
            if ( v9 >= v4 || v8 >= v6 )
              goto LABEL_16;
          }
        }
        v9 = 0;
        v8 = 0;
        v7 = 0;
LABEL_16:
        if ( v4 > v9 )
        {
          memcpy(&v15[v7], &v2[v9], v4 - v9);
          v6 = v14;
          v7 = v7 + v4 - v9;
        }
        if ( v8 < v6 )
          memcpy(&v15[v7], &v2[v8 + v4], v3 - v8 - v4);
        memcpy(v2, v15, v3);
      }
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

void BAD() 
{
  printf("BAD\n");
  exit(2);
}

void GOOD() 
{
  printf("GOOD\n");

  for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    printf("%d ", in_array[j]);

  printf("\n");
}
```

```
$ readelf -s chall | grep -E "in_array|GOOD|BAD|main" | grep -v libc
    44: 0000063d    46 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 BAD
    72: 000006d9    69 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 main
    78: 00002078    16 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 in_array
    79: 0000066b   110 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 GOOD
```

solve.py

```
import angr
import claripy

base = 0x400000
main, good, bad = base + 0x6d9, base + 0x66b, base + 0x63d
pointer_size = 4
in_array_addr, in_array_size = base + 0x2078, 16 * pointer_size

p = angr.Project('./chall')
state = p.factory.blank_state(addr=main)

arr = claripy.BVS('in_array', in_array_size)
for i in arr.chop(pointer_size):
  state.add_constraints(i >= 0)
  state.add_constraints(i < 17)
state.memory.store(in_array_addr, arr)

sm = p.factory.simulation_manager(state)

sm.explore(find=good, avoid=bad)
print('found ?', len(sm.found))

flag_state = sm.found[0]
flag_data = flag_state.memory.load(in_array, in_array_size)
print(flag_state.solver.eval(flag_data, cast_to=bytes).strip(b'\0\n'))
```

angr log

```
WARNING | cle.loader | The main binary is a position-independent executable. It is being loaded with a base address of 0x400000.
WARNING | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | The program is accessing memory or registers with an unspecified value. This could indicate unwanted behavior.
WARNING | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | angr will cope with this by generating an unconstrained symbolic variable and continuing. You can resolve this by:
WARNING | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 1) setting a value to the initial state
WARNING | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 2) adding the state option ZERO_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY,REGISTERS}, to make unknown regions hold null
WARNING | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 3) adding the state option SYMBOL_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY_REGISTERS}, to suppress these messages.
WARNING | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling memory at 0x7fff0000 with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x4006e0 (main+0x7 in chall (0x6e0))
WARNING | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling register ebp with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x4006e3 (main+0xa in chall (0x6e3))
WARNING | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling register esi with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x400721 (M+0x3 in chall (0x721))
WARNING | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling register ebx with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x400722 (M+0x4 in chall (0x722))
found ? 0
```

Comment: Using [`state.solver.add`](http://angr.io/api-doc/angr.html#angr.state_plugins.solver.SimSolver.add). Examples [here](https://docs.angr.io/core-concepts/solver#constraint-solving)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a few changes to the code you've posted, angr is able to find a solution.

The addresses of the symbol are resolved dynamically using `proj.loader.find_symbol`. This avoids hard coding the address which may each change each-time the source is recompiled.

Instead of declaring a big BitVector covering the entire array, I've declared 16 8-bit BitVectors, one each for every element of the array. This way it's easier to apply the constraints.

```
import angr

proj = angr.Project('./chall')

# Addresses of symbols
main = proj.loader.find_symbol('main').rebased_addr
good = proj.loader.find_symbol('GOOD').rebased_addr 
bad = proj.loader.find_symbol('BAD').rebased_addr 

in_array_addr = proj.loader.find_symbol('in_array').rebased_addr  

# in_array is a char array with 16 elements and sizeof(char)=1
in_array_size = 16 * 1

initial_state = proj.factory.entry_state(addr=main)

for i in range(in_array_size):
    # Each char of the array is a 8 bit BitVector
    ch = initial_state.solver.BVS('ch{}'.format(i), 8)

    # Add constraints
    initial_state.solver.add(ch >= 0)    
    initial_state.solver.add(ch < 17)

    # Store BV to memory
    initial_state.memory.store(in_array_addr+i, ch)


# Create a Simulation manager from the current state
sm = proj.factory.simulation_manager(initial_state)

# Find a path to good while avoiding bad
sm.explore(find=good, avoid=bad)

print("No. of solutions found:", len(sm.found))

if len(sm.found) > 0:        
    # Considering the first goal state
    goal_state = sm.found[0]

    # Load contents of memory at the said address
    flag_data = goal_state.memory.load(in_array_addr, in_array_size)

    # Convert flag_data from BitVector to bytes
    answer = goal_state.solver.eval(flag_data, cast_to=bytes)
    print (list(answer))
```

#### Output

```
user@70a6c29adea0 $ python solve.py
WARNING | 2019-07-04 21:09:04,764 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | The program is accessing memory or registers with an unspecified value. This could indicate unwa
nted behavior.
WARNING | 2019-07-04 21:09:04,764 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | angr will cope with this by generating an unconstrained symbolic variable and continuing. You ca
n resolve this by:
WARNING | 2019-07-04 21:09:04,764 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 1) setting a value to the initial state
WARNING | 2019-07-04 21:09:04,764 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 2) adding the state option ZERO_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY,REGISTERS}, to make unknown regions h
old null
WARNING | 2019-07-04 21:09:04,764 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 3) adding the state option SYMBOL_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY_REGISTERS}, to suppress these messa
ges.
WARNING | 2019-07-04 21:09:04,765 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling register edi with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x8048861 (__libc_csu_init+0x1 i
n chall (0x8048861))
WARNING | 2019-07-04 21:09:04,770 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling register ebx with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x8048863 (__libc_csu_init+0x3 i
n chall (0x8048863))
No. of solutions found: 1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

## UPDATE

After OP mentioned that its a challenge from Google CTF Quals 2019, I decided to look at the original binary instead.

Apparently the previous answer from angr doesn't satisfy the C code OP posted. There were a couple of reasons for this.

The first and glaring mistake was using the `goal_state` to load `flag_data`. This is wrong as in `goal_state` the `flag_data` will get changed.

The second mistake was the bytes of `in_array` should be in between 0 and 16 (not 0 and 17).

This can be inferred from the Ghidra decompiler screenshot.

[image]

The last line

```
return uVar2 & (uint)((byte)local_24[15] < 16);
```

checks whether the final element of the array is `< 16`.

The following updated script prints out the the contents of `in_array` which satisfies the constraints.

```
import angr

proj = angr.Project('./chall')

# Addresses of symbols
main = proj.loader.find_symbol('main').rebased_addr
good = proj.loader.find_symbol('GOOD').rebased_addr 
bad = proj.loader.find_symbol('BAD').rebased_addr 

in_array_addr = proj.loader.find_symbol('in_array').rebased_addr  
in_array_size = 16

initial_state = proj.factory.blank_state(addr=main)
flag = [None] * in_array_size

for i in range(in_array_size):
    # Each char of the array is a 8 bit BitVector
    ch = initial_state.solver.BVS('ch{}'.format(i), 8)
    flag[i] = ch

    # Add constraints
    initial_state.solver.add(ch >= 0)    
    initial_state.solver.add(ch < 16)

    # Store BV to memory
    initial_state.memory.store(in_array_addr+i, ch)


# Create a Simulation manager from the current state
sm = proj.factory.simulation_manager(initial_state)

# Find a path to good while avoiding bad
sm.explore(find=good, avoid=bad)

print("No. of solutions found:", len(sm.found))

if len(sm.found) > 0:        
    # Considering the first goal state
    goal_state = sm.found[0]       

    print([goal_state.solver.eval(d) for d in flag])
```

#### Output

```
user@ec03a79cf15f$ python solver.py
WARNING | 2019-07-06 10:29:07,128 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | The program is accessing memory or registers with an unspecified value. This could indicate unwanted behavior.
WARNING | 2019-07-06 10:29:07,128 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | angr will cope with this by generating an unconstrained symbolic variable and continuing. You can resolve this by:
WARNING | 2019-07-06 10:29:07,129 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 1) setting a value to the initial state
WARNING | 2019-07-06 10:29:07,129 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 2) adding the state option ZERO_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY,REGISTERS}, to make unknown regions hold null
WARNING | 2019-07-06 10:29:07,129 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 3) adding the state option SYMBOL_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY_REGISTERS}, to suppress these messages.
WARNING | 2019-07-06 10:29:07,129 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling memory at 0x7fff0000 with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x8048532 (main+0x7 in chall (0x8048532))
WARNING | 2019-07-06 10:29:07,131 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling register ebp with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x8048535 (main+0xa in chall (0x8048535))
WARNING | 2019-07-06 10:29:07,380 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling register ebx with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x8048567 (M+0x3 in chall (0x8048567))
No. of solutions found: 1
[9, 8, 7, 2, 11, 15, 13, 10, 6, 5, 14, 4, 3, 0, 12, 1]
```

Using the following as the contents of `in_array` solves the challenge.

```
[9, 8, 7, 2, 11, 15, 13, 10, 6, 5, 14, 4, 3, 0, 12, 1]
```

Comment: @Iddo I see. But this is the solution angr came up with. Maybe some other changes need to be made. Sharing the original challenge binary would be great.

Comment: @Iddo Check updated answer

Comment: The 17 was on purpose >< honeyput, thanks mate, u deserve more than the +50

Comment: @Iddo Thanks. Angr would still find a solution with `< 17` . `10, 8, 7, 2, 12, 16, 14, 11, 6, 5, 15, 4, 3, 0, 13, 1`  but this is not correct as far as the original challenge is concerned.

Comment: I have another related question hopefully you can help https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25571/angr-arm64-call-state-not-resolved